# RDF metadata in SVG collaborative work

Tags: svg, metadata, rdf

I can't find a good example of how annotate my nested SVG with RDF.
This is the rough structure of the document:

```
<svg>
<title>Main document</title>
<metadata>
This needs a title, publisher, date, cc:license, and cc:attributionURL.
</metadata>

 <svg>
 <title>Contribution 1</title>
  This needs a title, date, and contributor 1.
 </svg>

 <svg>
 <title>Contribution 2</title>
  This needs a title, date, and contributor 2.
 </svg>

</svg>
```

Comment: Should have posted to semantic overflow which I just discovered.

Answer (score 2):

here are the very first lines of a SVG document generated by inkscape. They put the RDF in the tag metadata.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="788.6123"
   height="864.14807"
   id="svg2"
   sodipodi:version="0.32"
   inkscape:version="0.46"
   sodipodi:docname="jeter2.svg"
   inkscape:output_extension="org.inkscape.output.svg.inkscape"
   version="1.0">
  <metadata
     id="metadata129">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
 <defs id="defs127">
```

Comment: <cc:Work rdf:about="">
Blank about refers to "this" document, or so I read. How about the contributors pieces which are separate sub works?

Comment: use `rdf:about="#object123"` to refer to a specific object, for instance `<path id="object123">`.

Comment: SVG is more complicated than a single "about" attribute. Could you provide a working example?